# Can pandas perform an aggregating operation involving two columns?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

Given the following dataframe,
is it possible to calculate the sum of `col2` and the sum of `col2 + col3`,
in a single aggregating function?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col3': [10, 20, 30, 40]})
```

| . | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | a | 2 | 20 |
| 2 | b | 3 | 30 |
| 3 | b | 4 | 40 |

In R's dplyr I would do it with a single line of `summarize`,
and I was wondering what might be the equivalent in pandas:

```
df %>% group_by(col1) %>% summarize(col2_sum = sum(col2), col23_sum = sum(col2 + col3))
```

**Desired result:**

| . | col1 | col2_sum | col23_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 3 | 33 |
| 1 | b | 7 | 77 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `assign` the new column first

```
out = df.assign(col23 = df.col2+df.col3).groupby('col1',as_index=False).sum()
```

Out[81]:

```
  col1  col2  col3  col23
0    a     3    30     33
1    b     7    70     77
```

From my understanding the `apply` is more like the `summarize` in R

```
out = df.groupby('col1').\
           apply(lambda x : pd.Series({'col2_sum':x['col2'].sum(),
                                       'col23_sum':(x['col2'] + x['col3']).sum()})).\
               reset_index()
Out[83]: 
  col1  col2_sum  col23_sum
0    a         3         33
1    b         7         77
```

Comment: Awesome, the `apply` + `pd.Series` part is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with `datar`:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, group_by, summarize, sum
>>> df = tibble(
...     col1=['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 
...     col2=[1, 2, 3, 4],
...     col3=[10, 20, 30, 40]
... )
>>> df >> group_by(f.col1) >> summarize(
...     col2_sum = sum(f.col2), 
...     col23_sum = sum(f.col2 + f.col3)
... )
      col1  col2_sum  col23_sum
  <object>   <int64>    <int64>
0        a         3         33
1        b         7         77
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.